# Adding constraint on an existing table with CHECK

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Can anyone have a look at my SQL statement and tell me what is wrong with it. I keep getting error when I tried to add a new constraint on an existing table.

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Note: these expressions look suspiciously like regular expressions: `[^A-L]` - they will not work with the `LIKE` operator how you may think they will. You may need to use `REGEXP_LIKE` (and remove the `%`s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parentheses around the entire condition for `check`:

```
alter table seat 
    add constraint check_seats
        CHECK ((BLOCKNO = 'FRONT' AND ROWNO NOT LIKE '%[^A-J]%'  AND SEATNO <=40) OR 
               (BLOCKNO = 'MIDDLE' AND ROWNO NOT LIKE '%[^A-L]%' AND SEATNO <=50) OR
               (BLOCKNO = 'BACK' AND ROWNO NOT LIKE '%[^A-N]%' AND SEATNO <=60)
              );
```

Comment: @NashTamu . . . It is unusual that you thanked me for this answer but chose the other answer.  Of course, as the OP, you have the right to accept whichever answer you like.

Answer (score 3):

Add one more parenthesis for the check constraint.

```
     CHECK ((BLOCKNO = 'FRONT' AND ROWNO NOT LIKE '%[^A-J]%'  AND SEATNO <=40) OR 
            (BLOCKNO = 'MIDDLE' AND ROWNO NOT LIKE '%[^A-L]%' AND SEATNO <=50) OR
            (BLOCKNO = 'BACK' AND ROWNO NOT LIKE '%[^A-N]%' AND SEATNO <=60)
           );
```

Comment: `'%[^A-J]%' ` mixes regex and non-regex syntax.  Consequently the NOT LIKE will always be true, regardless of the value of ROWNO.